# Taylor Series with undefined coefficients

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Hello can someone give me some hints? The problem:

[image]

So I have some questions about the task. I think to solve this I should consider this formulas:

$$  \frac{1}{h} \sum_{j=-m}^{j=m} \alpha_{j} f_{i+j} $$
$$  \sum_{j = - m}^{j  = m} \beta_{j} f_{i+j} $$
$$ h\sum_{j = -m}^{j = m} \gamma_j f_{i+j} $$

because I know the formula which looks like previous ones:

$$  f^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{h}\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_{i} f\left(x + p_i h \right)  $$
And then expand  $f(x + p_i h) $ in taylor's series. but in this formulas I have symbols that I don't understand for example the sum is defined from $-m$ to $m$ and I don't know what that changes. Can you also tell me what $\phi \left( \alpha , \beta, \gamma, f\right)$  and $\varphi \left( \alpha , \beta, \gamma, f\right)$ means? Can I assume that for current $\alpha , \beta , \gamma$ the $\phi \left( \alpha , \beta, \gamma, f\right) = f^{'}(x) $? I would appreciate if you link some good materials for this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the question is unclear. If you define $\varphi=\phi$ then $\phi-\varphi=0$ and is certainly $O(h),O(h^2)$, etc. To exclude such trivial solutions you should write the problem exactly as it appeared in your exercise sheet, because currently it does not make sense. You should also clarify what all the symbols mean.

Comment: @Snaw I can't understand the problem as well because I am asking I added the picture of the problem maybe now it will be much more clear for you to give me some suggestions. Thanks for your time

Comment: Is this about multi-step methods, or a Grand Unifying Theory of finite-difference methods? Are $f_i=f(x_i)$ with $x_{i+1}-x_i=O(h)$? Is $f$ the right side in $\dot x=f(x)$, and is the formula in some sense related to the approximate solution of this equation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann it's  finite-difference method

Comment: The definition of $\phi$ is obviously an image. Is there any hint in the surrounding context that there might be errors in that formula? That $f$ is not always the same, that derivative symbols are missing,...? The differences are apparently to represent truncation errors, but for what reference object? In the first case, why is it not possible to just define $\varphi=\phi+h$ or $=\phi+hf_i$?